# flutter textEditconroller

Tags: flutter, dart

I already have the value displayed by

```
lattextController.text = addr_data!.latitude!;
lngtextController.text = addr_data!.longitude!;
```

then i get data value sent from another page but when i update data It updates to the old value. It's not a new value. But new information was sent to textformfield It has to type something to update the latest information. Please help.

```
if (widget.lng != null && widget.lng!.isNotEmpty) {
  lngtextController.text = widget.lng!;
  print(widget.lng!);
}
if (widget.lat != null && widget.lat!.isNotEmpty) {
  lattextController.text = widget.lat!;
  print(widget.lat);
}
}
```

This is textformfield

```
 Widget lngTextFormField(String label, String keyword, String text) {
lngtextController.selection = TextSelection.collapsed(offset: lngtextController.text.length);

return TextFormField(
  controller: lngtextController,
  onChanged: (value) {
    saveAd(value, keyword);
  },
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: label,
    labelStyle: TextStyle(
      fontFamily: 'supermarket',
      fontSize: 16,
    ),
    isDense: true,
  ),
);
}
```

Comment: are you called that function on `initState` ? or where did you call it?

Comment: The code above I called on in initstateThe code above I called on in initstate